# Golang Type Switch: How to match a generic slice/array/map/chan?

Tags: go

How can I use a Go Type Switch to match a **generic** slice, array, map, or channel?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func WhatIsIt(x interface{}) {
    switch X := x.(type) {
        case bool:
            fmt.Printf("Type Switch says %#v is a boolean.\n", X)
        case int, int8, int16, int32, int64, uint, uint8, uint16, uint32, uint64:
            fmt.Printf("Type Switch says %#v is an integer.\n", X)
        case float32, float64, complex64, complex128:
            fmt.Printf("Type Switch says %#v is a floating-point.\n", X)
        case string:
            fmt.Printf("Type Switch says %#v is a string.\n", X)
        case []interface{}:
            fmt.Printf("TypeSwitch says %#v is a slice.\n", X)
        case map[interface{}]interface{}:
            fmt.Printf("TypeSwitch says %#v is a map.\n", X)
        case chan interface{}:
            fmt.Printf("TypeSwitch says %#v is a channel.\n", X)
        default:
            switch reflect.TypeOf(x).Kind() {
                case reflect.Slice, reflect.Array, reflect.Map, reflect.Chan:
                    fmt.Printf("TypeSwitch was unable to identify this item.  Reflect says %#v is a slice, array, map, or channel.\n", X)
                default:
                    fmt.Printf("Type handler not implemented: %#v\n", X)
            }
    }
}

func main() {
    WhatIsIt(true)
    WhatIsIt(1)
    WhatIsIt(1.5)
    WhatIsIt("abc")
    WhatIsIt([]int{1,2,3})
    WhatIsIt(map[int]int{1:1, 2:2, 3:3})
    WhatIsIt(make(chan int))
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Type Switch says true is a boolean.
Type Switch says 1 is an integer.
Type Switch says 1.5 is a floating-point.
Type Switch says "abc" is a string.
TypeSwitch was unable to identify this item.  Reflect says []int{1, 2, 3} is a slice, array, map, or channel.
TypeSwitch was unable to identify this item.  Reflect says map[int]int{1:1, 2:2, 3:3} is a slice, array, map, or channel.
TypeSwitch was unable to identify this item.  Reflect says (chan int)(0x104320c0) is a slice, array, map, or channel.
```

As you can see from the output, the `case []interface{}` fails to match the slice that I send in.  I need to resort to using the `reflect` package instead.

If I explicitly write `case []int`, then it works for my given example, but it's impossible to know all the input types ahead of time, so I need a more general solution.  I want to avoid using the `reflect` package if the Type Switch is able to handle this.

Is there any way to use the Type Switch to determine if an object is a slice/array/map/chan/etc...?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Type switches work with specific types.  If you cannot enumerate all of the types in the switch, then the only option is to use the reflect package.

```
v := reflect.ValueOf(x)
switch v.Kind() {
case reflect.Bool:
    fmt.Printf("bool: %v\n", v.Bool())
case reflect.Int, reflect.Int8, reflect.Int32, reflect.Int64:
    fmt.Printf("int: %v\n", v.Int())
case reflect.Uint, reflect.Uint8, reflect.Uint32, reflect.Uint64:
    fmt.Printf("int: %v\n", v.Uint())
case reflect.Float32, reflect.Float64:
    fmt.Printf("float: %v\n", v.Float())
case reflect.String:
    fmt.Printf("string: %v\n", v.String())
case reflect.Slice:
    fmt.Printf("slice: len=%d, %v\n", v.Len(), v.Interface())
case reflect.Map:
    fmt.Printf("map: %v\n", v.Interface())
case reflect.Chan:
    fmt.Printf("chan %v\n", v.Interface())
default:
    fmt.Println(x)
}
```